# Angular Router does not load my component despite correct URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to load my Angular component with my router, but it never shows up nor throws an error.

app-routing-module

```
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children:
      [
        { path: 'compare', component: CompareComponent, children:[] },
        {
          path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, children: [
            { path: 'new', component: ServerConnectionEditComponent }
          ]
        },
      ]
  },
```

app-server-connections

```
  constructor(private router:Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
  onAddServer()
  {
    console.log(this.route.url)
    this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

It seems the URL is valid, because any other URL throws an error.

app-server-connection-edit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("in Edit") //never gets here
  }
```

server-connections.component.html

```
...
<th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                  (click)="onAddServer()">+</button></th>
```

app-component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

settings.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="col-md-12" >
        <h4>Server Connections:</h4>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <app-server-connections [serverConnections]="serverConnections"></app-server-connections>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which url are you trying to navigate to?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/home/settings/new

Comment: Do you have enough `<router-outlet>`'s set up? Remember that when using `children`, each parent component needs a `<router-outlet>` in its template.

Comment: If I add <router-outlet> the component loads right away, and I want it to load on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have 1 level nested child in your route. So change your route like this. If this is not work open browser console to see if it there any error

```
{
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children:
    [
        { path: 'compare', component: CompareComponent },
        {
            path: 'settings/new', component: ServerConnectionEditComponent

        },
        { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
    ]
}
```

And make sure add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
 inside your app.component.html

Comment: Now it just loads my copmonent instead of my ServerConnectionsComponent instead of next to it.

Comment: settings.component.html
```<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="col-md-12" >
        <h4>Server Connections:</h4>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <app-server-connections [serverConnections]="serverConnections"></app-server-connections>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

server-connections.component.html
```
...
              <th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                  (click)="onAddServer()">+</button></th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: just change the route order i just update my answer

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: This worked, but how do you go further levels down?

Answer (score 1):

The more specific must come in order before the less specific.  So,  settings/new must be in order before settings.